# How can I hide all studios from the search results in Airbnb?

Tags: accommodation, airbnb

Definitions:

- Studio apartment = An apartment with a single room space containing bed/kitchen/living room.
- 1-bedroom apartment = An apartment where the bed is in a different room than the kitchen/living room.

I am looking for a 1-bedroom apartment  on AirBnB. I see there is a filter on the number of bedrooms, but that doesn't seem to eliminate most studios:

[image]

Is there a better way to hide more studios from the search results in Airbnb? E.g, removing  any listing containing the word "studio"?

Comment: Probably no because hosts like to exaggerate their listings for better search results.

Comment: @JonathanReez such a time waste to use. Hopefully one day some strong competitor emerges and cleans that mess.

Answer (score -2):

Try adding "independent bedroom" or "separate bedroom" to your search, or even just type "1 bedroom, 1BR apartment, It'll give you a more focused result and can help minimize the chance of spending too much time poring over irrelevant studios. Additionally, filtering your search by Host Language and Location can further fast-track your findings and slim down your search pool.

Comment: Thanks, where do we add  "independent bedroom" or "separate bedroom" in the search? I don't see any search box where I can enter keywords.

Comment: In the search bar, enter "separate bedroom"  with double quotes    and add the necessary filters to fit your preferences.

Comment: thanks, sorry where do you see the search bar? I don't see any:  https://i.stack.imgur.com/8CSup.jpg

Comment: I also don't see any search bar on the AirBnB website or app. Even if there is one I'm missing ,wouldn't this also exclude lots of non-studio apartments which just don't happen to use the term "independent bedroom" in their description? How is filtering by host language going to affect whether results are studios or not?

Comment: I can't share a picture, but in my end there is a search bar on the top beside the logo.

Comment: Pics or it didn't happen. How do you access airbnb? https://www.airbnb.com/ or phone app?

Comment: There is no option to send pic. here, but I'm using an Airbnb phone application.

Comment: https://support.google.com/android/answer/9075928?hl=en https://support.apple.com/en-gb/guide/iphone/iphc872c0115/ios please see these articles on how to take a screenshot.